# Spring security root path can be bypassed with any special characters except "/" of most services

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring security and I am using  tag for the links.
below is one of the urls,

```
<filter-invocation-definition-source id="objectDefinitionSource">
<intecept-url pattern = "/oneLink/**" access = "admin"/>
</filter-invocation-definition-source>
```

While accessing localhost:8080/oneLink, I can able to redirected to the page. But when "?" is added, as :"localhost:8080/oneLink?" the info is getting leaked(without login, any user can see the data).

Data is getting leaked, if I add any character except "/" after oneLink.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your code using below snippet

**Example Snippet**

```
<filter-invocation-definition-source id="objectDefinitionSource">
<intecept-url pattern = "/oneLink*/**" access = "admin"/>
</filter-invocation-definition-source>
```

Let me know if that resolved your issue.

Comment: Tried earlier with the given snippet. it is not working.

Comment: Can you post or send your entire security config and web.xml?
It is tough to comment without knowing entire config.

Comment: @swetha  Please try once gain with the updated snippet.. and let me know if that resolves the issue